# PyQt5 button click animation

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

Good morning.

**Question 1**
In my code I am trying to make it so when you click on a button, it flashes red for a few milliseconds.

As you can see, I have a fade and unfade function. How can the fade function know it has to change the StyleSheet of the button that's calling the function?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QTimer)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, QPainter, QColor)


# Font declaration
mainFont = QFont("arial", 18, QFont.Bold)


# Color declaration
"""

backgroundColor = "#2e3436"
buttonColor = "#729fcf"
textColor = "#2e3436"
greenColor = "#27bc10"
redColor = "#d81711"

"""

backgroundColor = "#2e3436"
buttonColor = "#ffffff"
textColor = "#000000"

greenColor = "#27bc10"
redColor = "#d81711"

# main buttons size
mainWidth = 160
mainHeight = 80


# Variable declaration
CurrentSpeed = 1


class MainInterface(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):




        b1 = QPushButton('Start')
        b1.setFixedWidth(mainWidth)
        b1.setFixedHeight(mainHeight)
        b1.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s; color: %s" % (greenColor, textColor))
        b1.setFont(mainFont)
        b1.clicked.connect(self.fade)

        b2 = QPushButton('Stop')
        b2.setFixedWidth(mainWidth)
        b2.setFixedHeight(mainHeight)
        b2.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s; color: %s" % (redColor, textColor))
        b2.setFont(mainFont)

        b3 = QPushButton('Speed -')
        b3.setFixedWidth(mainWidth)
        b3.setFixedHeight(mainHeight)
        b3.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s; color: %s" % (buttonColor, textColor))
        b3.setFont(mainFont)

        l1 = QLabel(str(CurrentSpeed))
        l1.setStyleSheet("color: white; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid white")
        l1.setFont(mainFont)
        l1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        b4 = QPushButton('Speed +')
        b4.setFixedWidth(mainWidth)
        b4.setFixedHeight(mainHeight)
        b4.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s; color: %s" % (buttonColor, textColor))
        b4.setFont(mainFont)



        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setColumnMinimumWidth(50, 400)
        grid.setRowMinimumHeight(10, 250)

        grid.addWidget(b1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(b2, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(b3, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(l1, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(b4, 1, 2)




        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % backgroundColor)    
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 850, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.show()

    def fade(self, button):
        button.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.unfade)

    def unfade(self):
        button.setWindowOpacity(1)
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2e3436")







if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    ex = MainInterface()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Question 2**

More advanced, how would I make an animation on the button similar to when you click on the lockscreen of your phone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, slots can call `self.sender()` to find out object that emitted signal.

Next, you have to be mindful of the signal payload, which in this case is an optional "checked True/False", so button is not a valid parameter for fade()  slot.

It is also advisable to decorate slots with `pyqtSlot`, there is no disadvantage and even if its advantages are not relevant now, they will be later (and save you some bugs related to signal handling when decorator not used, as posted on mailing list). As pointed out by ehkumoro, since the checked is optional and you don't use it, it is sufficient to decorate with pyqtSlot().

Finally, `unfade()` needs to know which button to unfade; a lambda as done by eyllanesc is fine but I'll show how to do it with data member, which has the advantage that it plays role of a "state flag" on `MainInterface`. I.e. when not None, it indicates that `MainInterface` widget is "currently fading a button"; this often comes in handy when your widget responds to an event that occurs between end of `fade()` and start of `unfade()`, like another click (widget needs to test if it is already fading another button).

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.__fading_button = None

@pyqtSlot()
def fade(self):
    self.__fading_button = self.sender()  # enter the "fading button" state
    self.__fading_button.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
    self.__fading_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
    QTimer.singleShot(300, self.unfade)

def unfade(self):
    self.__fading_button.setWindowOpacity(1)
    self.__fading_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2e3436")
    self.__fading_button = None  # exit the "fading button" state
```

Comment: For signals like `clicked(bool checked=false)`, you can use `@pyqtSlot()`, which eliminates the dead argument.